# I saw him going to city. I saw him go to city

Tags: syntactic-analysis, progressive-aspect, gerund-vs-infinitive, sense-verbs

1:I saw him going to city. 
2:I saw him go to city.

First one refers to Gerund. Second one refers to infinite. 
Do they have the same meanings or changed?
Define it with reasons.

Comment: Similar questions have been answered here. You may find the answer(s) by searching the site.

Comment: Share link please.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=saw+him

Comment: I could not find the solution to the problem. Please define it in your sentences .

Comment: @User124234: 1. In your first example, "going" is not a *gerund*, as you've mentioned. It's the *present participle*. 2. Your second uses a term, "infinite". Are you referring to the verb form, *infinitive*? The link RegDwight posted for you deals with a similar question and an answer is right there.